# Crawling the web without increasing page views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-crawler

I am working on a search engine like tool that will crawl through the websites, collect data, index it and make it available for search within my application.
I'll be using `Net::HTTP` or `Hpricot` to crawl the websites.
The sites I am crawling are forums, which keep views and replies count for each thread. Whenever I crawl through view count will be increasing.

Is there any way to avoid this? How search engines are crawling without increasing view count?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the remote sites increment their counters. If they take into consideration `User-Agent` headers you could take advantage of that. If their counters are incremented via javascript (like Google Analytics) then `Net::HTTP` shouldn't trigger changes.